# Question regarding 3D vectors and their angles

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I recently came across this in my Vectors textbook.

[image]

I don't quite follow the logic that ends with $\cos^2\alpha + \cos^2\beta + \cos^2\gamma = 1$. I understand that unit vectors have magnitude 1, and that they are achieved by dividing a vector $\overrightarrow v$ by its magnitude $\vert \vec v \vert$ which produces the unit vector $\hat v$. Is $a$ considered a vector here, such that dividing it by $\vert \vec u \vert$ produces a unit vector?

As I am just starting to learn about vectors, a rudimentary explanation of why $\cos^2\alpha + \cos^2\beta + \cos^2\gamma = 1$ would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\hat u=u_x\hat i + u_y\hat j + u_z\hat k$ is a unit vector then its magnitude equals one as does the square of its magnitude.

Therefore, $u_x^2 +u_y^2 + u_z^2=1$.

But $$u_x=\cos\alpha$$
    $$u_y=\cos\beta$$
    $$u_z=\cos\gamma$$
so plugging those into the above gives the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm confused about how you got the left side: $u_x^2 + u_y^2 + u_z^2 = 1$. If this side is supposed to be the square of  $u_x + u_y + u_z$, don't you have to expand the trinomial (like FOIL for binomials)?

Comment: @Kman3 No. The expression $(u_x+u_y+u_z)$ is not the same as $u_x\hat i+ u_y\hat j +u_z\hat k$. We can't square the latter using FOIL because terms like $\hat i\hat j$ are undefined.

Comment: So when you stated that "its magnitude equals one as does the square of its magnitude",  I assume you mean that $\vert \hat u \vert = \vert \hat u \vert^2 = 1$. So with that knowledge, how do I get to your conclusion, that $u_x^2 + u_y^2 + u_z^2 = 1$? Thanks

Comment: $|\hat x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$.

Comment: Ah! I see. Just for reference, is that a formula with a certain name, or is it a logical conclusion due to properties of vectors?

Comment: It is a logical conclusion. It follows from the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, $a$ is one component of the vector $\vec{u}$. A unit vector is obtained by dividing $\vec{u}$, one component at a time, by $|\vec{u}|$. So $\cos^2\alpha+\cdots=\frac{a^2}{u^2}+\cdots=\frac{a^2+\cdots}{u^2}=\frac{u^2}{u^2}=1$.

Comment: Hi! I appreciate you helping me. Can you clarify why $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = u^2$?

Comment: @Kman3 This is the Pythagorean theorem in $3$ dimensions.

Comment: Thanks very much!